# Как купить мороженое во множественном числе?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Собираясь купить мороженое Фруктовый лёд, никак не могла понять, как правильно сказать. "Пожалуйста, два Фруктовых льда", — звучит кривовато, по-моему.

И насчёт мороженого вообще: два мороженых, две мороженые или два мороженое"? Что-то я совсем запуталась.

P.S. Конечно, можно сказать просто: "Два брикета мороженого (или мороженых)", ну а если не видно упаковки мороженого — не рожок, не брикет, и не понятно что это, то как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы изрядно вопрос запутали. Не сразу и поймешь, о чем спрашиваете. Да и вопросов тут явно не один.
Отвечаю на вопрос AS IS (как понял).

Перво-наперво: как сказать так, чтобы сомнений не было?
***Две штуки мороженого. Две штуки фруктового льда и т.д.***

Теперь о формах в упомянутых сочетаниях.
***Два фруктовых льда.*** Никаких проблем.
Это не множественное число. Это число, так сказать, двойственное. Форма, совпадающая с родительным единственного.
Сложнее будет сказать ***Пять фруктовых льдов***. Потому что использование слова "лёд" во множественном числе несвободно. Но форма есть, поэтому указанный вариант вполне возможен.

***Одно мороженое. Два мороженых. Пять мороженых***.
Вообще никаких сложностей. Мороженое склоняется как зеленое или круглое.
Единственная разница: "мороженое" ― субстантивированное причастие. Т. е. причастие, превратившееся в существительное.
(Спор о том, была ли *исходная* форма причастием или отглагольным прилагательным, я здесь опускаю.)