# Правильно ли: "Два ванильных мороженых, пожалуйста"?

Tags: выбор-слов, существительные

Можно ведь сказать:

> Два ванильных мороженых, пожалуйста.

но некорректно употреблять слово "мороженое" во множественном числе:

> мороженые

?

*P.S.* Пытался понять, является ли слово *мороженое* конкретным существительным и кажется, что можно. Но всё-таки лучше уточнить.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как купить мороженое во множественном числе?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21025/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5) Кроме того, мороженое пишется с одной Н.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Спасибо за орфографию!

Comment: Не за что. ))))

Answer (score 3):

Можно сказать: две порции ванильного мороженого или два ванильных мороженых.

Реально форма "мороженых" употребляется только **в количественно-именных сочетаниях:** В толковых словарях **не указывается наличие формы мн. числа**, потому числовой вариант можно отнести к разговорной речи.

Примеры:

Он протянул продавщице деньги на два мороженых и стал смотреть в сторону, пока Фролова отштампует прохладные кругляшки (Альберт Лиханов).

Папе и Кате даже премию выплатили! Они тогда себе купили два мороженых. И еще маме ― одну порцию.

Была взята бутылка портвейна «Азербайджан» и два мороженых ― на закуску (Андрей Макаревич).

Answer (score 0):

Согласно Викисловарю ([см.](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)), существительное *мороженое* во множественном числе употребляться может. И во-вторых, мне кажется, что такое словосочетание вполне корректно и не должно вызывать каких-либо вопросов. Данное предложение является контекстуально-неполным: подразумевается сказуемое ***дайте***.