# Нормативность форм "две бедноты, два шашлыка, два мороженых"

Tags: грамматика

Продолжаю тему, начатую здесь
[Сколько падежей в русском языке?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440993)
и частично здесь
[Правильно ли: "Два ванильных мороженых, пожалуйста"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418627)

**Нормативность форм "две бедноты, два шашлыка, два мороженых"**.
Вопрос в том, насколько нормативны конструкции сами по себе и какой падеж у существительного.

Есть предположение, что это особая счетная форма, ибо она индицирует наличие грамматически нормативного множественного числа. Но тут действительно путано.

> У вас "две бедноты" в значении "два бедняка" или "две бедности"?

Строго говоря, ни в одном из этих значений. Второе, впрочем, ближе.
Я же имел в виду просто саму возможность пересчитать принципиально несчитаемое. В полемической, например, фразе типа ***"Беднота нашего района и беднота соседнего - это две разные бедноты!"***. 
Само слово выбрано случайно, можете взять "детвора" или "листва" - любое из списка слов, совершенно не предполагающих нормативного образования множественного числа. Но в этих специфических "счетных формах" выглядят грамматически допустимыми. Вот "пять беднот" или "шесть детвор" - это уже за гранью не только смысла, но и грамматики.

Comment: У вас "две бедноты" в значении "два бедняка" или "две бедности"?

Comment: Ни в каком из этих двух. Подробности - в тексте ответа.

Comment: Тут прикольно получилось. Вы на автомате написали: *Подробности - в тексте **ответа***. Подумал, что вы собираетесь отвечать на свой вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

Очень интересный вопрос. Здесь всё интересно получается.

"Шашлыка", "мороженого" — это форма родительного падежа (вопрос *два чего?*), а "бедноты" — форма именительного падежа (вопрос *две что?*).

У слова "мороженое" можно выделить два значения: изделие в упаковке с завода и само блюдо, которое иногда можно купить на развес (например, в кафе) или приготовить дома.

В первом варианте вполне корректно "два мороженых". Сказать "две порции" не совсем правильно, так как это не порция, а единица товара, полноценное изделие, имеющее разную форму (что отличимо от двух мешков сахара) и изготовленное на заводе, которое можно только купить целиком.

Во втором варианте это блюдо как вещество, которое необходимо измерять порциями при единственном числе: *можно две порции мороженого по 100 грамм*.

Если дома приготовили шоколадное и пломбирное мороженое, то корректно сказать "два вида мороженого". Так обычно и говорят.

---

Шашлык — это блюдо. Фразу "два шашлыка" можно понять трёхзначно: два кусочка или две порции, нанизанные на что-то, или два вида шашлыка.
Если кто-то скажет:
— У меня есть два шашлыка.
— Хм, а что ты имеешь в виду?
В словарях у шашлыка нет значения порции, а уж тем более кусочка. Исходя из этого, "два шашлыка" нельзя считать нормативным.

---

Только форму единственного числа имеют:
большинство собирательных существительных: учительство, студенчество, **листва**, зверьё, вороньё, **детвора**.
https://unotices.com/page-answer.php?id=11035

Нормативным "две бедноты" точно считать нельзя. Оно тяжело воспринимается на слух, как и "две листвы" и "две детворы". Тут нужно рассматривать стилистику. Если стилистически такое употребление целесообразно (а в вашем примере это так), то это сопоставимо с нестандартным использованием слова. То есть нужно закавычить или уйти от множественного числа:
*Беднота нашего района и беднота соседнего - это два разных вида бедноты!*

Comment: "Два кусочка" - неверное понимание: шашлык - наименование _всего_ блюда (этимологически 6 кусков мяса). От такого представления и возникло просторечное "приглашать на шашлык**и**". Множественное число вполне допустимо в контексте, подразумевающем штучность (шашлык на шампуре или заказываемая порция в ином виде), - так же и с мороженым.

Comment: "*в контексте, подразумевающем штучность.*" — Согласен. Тогда необходимо уточнение, указывающее на штучность. Но это более целесообразно с чётко выраженной товарной единицей, что сводит на нет элементы просторечия. Хотя я бы скорее сказал "*2 шампура с шашлыком(-ами)*", чем "*2 шашлыка на шампуре(-ах)*". Этимологию нашёл другую. Слово *шиш* по-тюркски — «пика», «штык», а *лик* — «для». Однако слово частенько употребляется в значении кусочков: *шампур с шашлыками, в миске ещё много шашлыков, возьмём по шашлычку?* (пример в словаре Кузнецова) - может, и в словари войдёт само значение кусочка.