# Множественное число слова "мороженое" без числительного

Tags: грамматика

Насколько я знаю, допустимо говорить "одно мороженое", "два мороженых".
Но можно ли сказать "шоколадные мороженые" или "мороженые растаяли"? 
Мне режет слух например, я бы даже если брикетов много, а числительного нет, употребил как неисчисляемое:
"шоколадное мороженое" или "мороженое растаяло".

Верно ли утверждение, что если числительного не стоит, то не используем слово во множественном числе ("мороженые") и всегда пишем "мороженое"?

Этот вопрос не является дубликатом [этого](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21025/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5), поскольку состоит именно в употреблении без числительного.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как купить мороженое во множественном числе?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21025/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Comment: Любое существительное (во мн. ч.) употребимо без числительного.

Comment: Это не дубликат! Без числительного!

Comment: Здесь более похожий вопрос: [Правильно ли: “Два ванильных мороженых, пожалуйста.”](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418627/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: Да, то что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: Вот только там ответы противоречивые :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильно ли: "Два ванильных мороженых, пожалуйста."](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418627/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

В академических словарях (толковых и орфографических) форма множественного числа не указывается. С другой стороны, в литературе встречаются выражения типа: "на столе были разные мороженые".

Приведу цитату из книги доктора филологических наук А.К. Карпова "Современный русский язык: Словообразование. Морфология":

> Если словоизменительная парадигма прилагательного **мороженое** состоит из
>   24 словоформ (в единственном числе мужского, женского, среднего рода —
>   по 6 падежных форм + во множественном числе — 6 падежных форм),
>   существительного **мороженое** — 12 словоформ (по 6 падежных форм, в
>   единственном и **множественном числе**).

Из этой цитаты можно сделать вывод, что в русском языке имеются все падежные формы множественного числа слова **мороженое**.

Answer (score 1):

> Верно ли утверждение, что если числительного не стоит, то не
>   используем слово во множественном числе ("мороженые") и всегда пишем
>   "мороженое"?

Не совсем так. Я бы отнес множественное число у "мороженного" к формам очень ограниченного употребления.

В разговорной и экспрессивной речи, полагаю, возможно что-то наподобие "Не знаю я никаких мороженных!", но этим, пожалуй, сфера употребления и ограничивается. Другой контекст - по аналогии, скажем, с техническими маслами, минеральными водами или горячими блюдами тут вряд ли возможен.
Мороженое, как и заливное, печеное, верченое, квашеное, томленое, духовое и проч. - все это частично подзабытые названия блюд русской кухни - в обычных ситуациях прекрасно обходится без множественного числа.

Что касается вопроса, к которому вас отсылают, то там речь идет о штуках (порциях) мороженого, это особый разговор. Аналогично и в отношении упомянутых "заливных", "духовых" и прочего. Эти формы мн. ч. могут употребляться с числительным.

Comment: Насчет заливного я не уверен. Пример: Ассортимент продуктов в желе включает 5 ассорти: «Венское», «Мясное с грибами», «Праздничное», «Особое», «Домашнее», языки и говядину в сметанном желе с хреном, два заливных (с ветчиной и с языком) и зельц «Тоскана». [Секреты успеха пищевых добавок фирмы «Альми» (2004) // «Мясная индустрия», 2004.09.27]

Comment: М_Г, но у вас же эта форма при числительном. ))) Здесь вопросов нет.

Answer (score 0):

> Реально форма "мороженых" употребляется только в количественно-именных сочетаниях. ([Правильно ли: "Два ванильных мороженых, пожалуйста."](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418627/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0))

Можно сказать "два шоколадных мороженых", но не "шоколадные мороженые".
Можно сказать "два мороженых растаяли", но не "мороженые растаяли".