# Почему два пирожных, а не два пирожного?

Tags: морфология, существительные, лексическая-сочетаемость

Числительные два, три, четыре и оба, стоя в формах именительного и винительного падежей, управляют формой родительного падежа единственного числа зависимого существительного: два <три, четыре, оба> торта, но не *два <три, четыре, оба> тортов. Однако на самом деле это не всегда верно. Так, нужно сказать два пирожных, но не *два пирожного. Какое свойство слова пирожное, отличное от свойства слова торт, делает единственно правильной именно конструкцию с формой множественного числа? Какие примеры слов в этом отношении не отличаются от слова пирожное?

Comment: Вот тут тоже есть похожие рассуждения. 1. Как купить мороженое во множественном числе?  http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21025/Как-купить-мороженое-во-множественном-числе. 2. Правильно ли: “Два ванильных мороженых, пожалуйста.”  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418627/Правильно-ли-Два-ванильных-мороженых-пожалуйста/418633#418633

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Причина в том, что "пирожное" - это субстантивированное прилагательное, причем оно *не* женского рода. Два *красивых* торта, два *красных* платья, два *вкусных пирожных*, но две *симпатичные* девушки.

Comment: Или сущ. адъективного склонения. В составе количественных сочетаний существительные адъективного склонения ведут себя абсолютно так же, как прилагательные:  оба участковых милиционера и оба участковых; три столовых ложки и три столовых, три столовые ложки и три столовые; два вторых блюда и два вторых (порядковое числительное второй склоняется так же, как прилагательное).  А конец вопроса - примеры слов?

Comment: Ну, это любые субстантивированные прилагательные не женского рода. Я думал, я всё и так объяснил. )

Comment: Очень уж кратко Вы объясняете, здесь ведь не только умудрённые опытом, но и молодые, начинающие знатоки. Хотелось бы именно толкования, что и почему. И по поводу женского рода тоже, это ведь культура речи, далеко не все знают. Но ответ верен, принимаю.

Answer (score 4):

А вы добавьте к слову "пирожных" существительное, как к прилагательному, например: *два пирожных кольца*. Слово *кольца*, как полагается при числительном *два*, употреблено в единственном числе, а *пирожных* - во множественном. Убираем существительное - остаётся "пирожных", которое принимает  функции существительного на себя.

Ср.: ЗАЛИВНОЕ. *Ассортимент продуктов в желе включает 5 ассорти: «Венское», «Мясное с грибами», «Праздничное», «Особое», «Домашнее», языки и говядину в сметанном желе с хреном, **два заливных** (с ветчиной и с языком) и зельц «Тоскана».* [Секреты успеха пищевых добавок фирмы «Альми» (2004) // «Мясная индустрия», 2004.09.27

Ср.: ВТОРОЕ. *Мне два вторых,  пожалуйста. - Мне два вторых (блюда).*

***Он сильно проголодался и взял себе два вторых: капусту с сосисками и котлету с гречневой кашей. [Ирина Муравьева. Мещанин во дворянстве (1994)]*** (примеры из Нацкорпуса)

Answer (score 2):

Я тут немножко порядочек наведу.

Во-первых, про субстантивацию. Пирожное - оно не изделие. Это бывшее прилагательное при слове "кушанье". Так же образованы субстантиваты по способу приготовления блюда  "мороженое", "жаркое", "холодное", "заливное" и масса устаревающих (верченое, копченое, вареное, жареное, тушеное, томленое), которые ранее использовались как обозначение кушанья, но сейчас теряют субстанивированность.

Во-вторых, женский род тут не критичен. Возьмите "купчая", "закладная", "столовая" - все равно "две купчие/купчих" или "три столовые/столовых" - это множественное число в любом случае. Автор принятого ответа, вероятно, спутал с правилом для определений при числительном (две красных ягоды, кофты, горы и две красные ягоды, кофты, горы). Для субстантиватов эта двойственность нормативной формы неактуальна.

Итак.

> Так, нужно сказать два пирожных, но не *два пирожного. Какое свойство
>   слова пирожное, отличное от свойства слова торт, делает единственно
>   правильной именно конструкцию с формой множественного числа?

То и только то правило, что "пирожное", как и "мороженое", "заливное", "жаркое" а так же "рабочий", "выходной", "приданое", "столовая" и многие другие независимо от рода являются субстантиватами, бывшими прилагательными (чаще - отглагольными и причастиями) и потому требуют словоизменения по образцу прилагательных.

С точки зрения исторической науки все объяснимо тем, что "родительный единственного" при числительных исторически восходит к так называемому двойственному числу, имеющему падежные формы, отличающиеся от единственного и множественного. Именительный падеж двойственного для существительных в ряде случаев совпадал с родительным единственного и с утерей в языке двойственного числа как такового уже полностью слился с ним.

У прилагательных двойственного числа специальных форм не было (вернее сказать, они утратились на очень ранней стадии, задолго до падения двойственного числа в целом). Таким образом прилагательные и причастия порождают субстантиваты, изменяющиеся по образцу множественного числа прилагательных. Пирожное - в их числе.

.=.=.=.=.=.

И добавлю немного к экскурсу в этимологию слова "пирожное".
Его чаще всего возводят к "пирог", что верно лишь отчасти.
Но на самом-то деле, как легко видеть, названия таких блюд сплошь отглагольные прилагательные.
Как затесалось сюда обычное прилагательное от существительного "пирог", не совсем ясно. Однако, если допустить вторичную аналогию с "творог" (от "творить"), то пирожное - отглагольное прилагательное от никогда не существовавшего глагола "пирить" (его правильная форма "пировать"). Этот лингвистический казус объясняется, видимо, тем, что "ог"- исторический суффикс субстантивации глаголов (творог-творить) и его появление в слове "пирог" (от "пир") - следствие какой-то лингвистической флюктуации. 
Видимо, все это и заставляет относиться носителей языка к слову "пирожное" не просто как к прилагательному, но прилагательному отглагольному, со всеми вытекающими отсюда нормами словоизменения  и использования.

Comment: *все равно "две купчих" или "три столовых"*  — А почему в учебниках по русскому языку пишут, что для женского рода склонение такое, как у прилагательных? "Две столовые", например. И Д.Э. Розенталь тоже приводит это правило с большим [количеством примеров](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=5vY_AAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%22+-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8&dq=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%22+-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-jbjMj_ffAhUNpYsKHb3pB6w4ChDoAQhIMAY).

Comment: @grizzly Да все правильно там пишут. Предпочтительная форма "две столовые", при том, что  "две столовых" не ошибка, а в некотором контекте и более правильно. Но ошибка не фактическая, а методическая. Вспоминать это правило в контексте пирожных нет никакого смысла, оно ничего не добавляет к пониманию поведения субстантиватов. Вопрос-то стоит не о том, как склонять, а о том, какое число, единственное или множественное, использовать.Никак не "не две столовой" - это-то понятно?! Впрочем, спасибо. Я этот момент в своем ответе чуть подробнее изложил.

Comment: *Никак не "не две столовой" - это-то понятно?!* — Разве автор принятого ответа утверждал что-то обратное?!

Comment: *"две столовых" не ошибка, а в некотором контекте и более правильно* — думаю, что ошибка, я бы так не сказал. Розенталь тоже не считает этот вариант допустимым. У Вас есть какие-то аргументы?

Comment: @grizzly  *Розенталь тоже не считает* Пождите, сечас посмотрю Розенталя. Вы меня испугали.

Comment: *Разве автор принятого ответа утверждал что-то обратное?!* Я не понял этого вопроса. Что вы называете "обратным"?! Давайте лучше вы мне объясните, что он утвеождал, когда вспомнил о "неженском" роде.

Comment: Вот Розенталь на которого я ориентируюсь, http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_03  Покажите мне, пожалуйста, где здесь ваш текст "из учебника". Или дайте нормальную ссылку, откуда вы соскринили свою картинку.

Comment: Практическая стилистика - 87. https://cloud.mail.ru/public/7HZn/vqh5Q6t7K  Стр. 85 - все аналогично предыдущему. Никаких запретов на форму родительного падежа нет.

Comment: По поводу своих претензий — забираю все назад и возвращаю взамен извинения. Глупости наговорил. За автора принятого ответа тогда уж тем более отдуваться не буду :) Сорри.

Answer (score 0):

"Пирожное" по сути - это "пирог", разрезанный на части.  Структура этого слова, наподобие "мороженого", имеет форму причастия, хотя оно является существительным.
В то время как "торт" имеет чёткую форму существительного. К тому же,  без окончания.

Comment: А *творожный, дорожный, судорожный, сапожный* и мн. др. — все эти слова тоже "наподобие "мороженого", имеет форму причастия"?

Comment: Что от "пирог", я согласна, но форма причастия - нет, это субстантивированное  прилагательное: не как "мороженое", а как "творожное" (творог).

Comment: Нет,  не имеют.  Мороженое морозили, пирожное не "пирожили", конечно, но резали. Ваши примеры имеют инную форму и семантику.

Comment: А ещё есть "горячее".

Comment: Это _пирожное изделие_, а не разрезанный пирог. Зализняк считает очевидным происхождение слова "пирожное" от ранее известного прилагательного "пирожный": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQHXI4GEHKw (Происхождение слова «пирожное»)

Comment: Зализняк по поводу пирожного читает очень интересную лекцию. Я смотрел. С этимологией всё понятно и без него, но я говорю о семантике. А с мороженым как быть, с горячим? Неужели никто не может понять, о чем я?